# How to Load Multiple Texture using OpenGL and C++?

Tags: c++, image, opengl

Following my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922425/how-do-i-swap-images-using-opengl-and-obj-c) to swap image using OpenGL and Obj-C, I decided to also go with the [original tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnXDUFq7T6A&list=PLRtjMdoYXLf6zUMDJVRZYV-6g6n62vet8&index=16&t=1262s) using C++ with shader and texture. What I'm trying to do is switching different texture. Here's my **[UPDATED]** code

```
#include <iostream>
#define  GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "SOIL2/SOIL2.h"
#include "Shader.h"

using namespace std;

//window
const GLuint WIDTH = 750, HEIGHT = 750;
int main( )
{
    glfwInit( );

    //GLFW
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE ); //only for mac
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE );

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow( WIDTH, HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr );

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize( window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight );

    if ( nullptr == window )
    {
        cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << endl;
        glfwTerminate( );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );

    //ModernOpenGL
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if ( GLEW_OK != glewInit( ) )
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //viewport
    glViewport( 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight );

    //enable alpha
    glEnable( GL_BLEND );
    glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );

    //shaders
    Shader ourShader( "resources/shaders/core.vs", "resources/shaders/core.frag" );

    //vertices
    GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        //position            //color              //texture Coords
        1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, // Top Right
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom Right
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom Left
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f  // Top Left
    };

    GLuint indices[] =
    {
        0, 1, 3, // 1st triangle
        1, 2, 3  // 2nd triangle
    };

    GLuint VBO, VAO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &VAO );
    glGenBuffers( 1, &VBO );
    glGenBuffers( 1, &EBO );

    glBindVertexArray( VAO );

    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( vertices ), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO );
    glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( indices ), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    //position
    glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof( GLfloat ), ( GLvoid * ) 0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    //color
    glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof( GLfloat ), ( GLvoid * )( 3 * sizeof( GLfloat )));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    //texture Coord
    glVertexAttribPointer( 2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof( GLfloat ), ( GLvoid * )( 6 * sizeof( GLfloat )));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 2 );

    glBindVertexArray( 0 ); // unbind VAO



    //CREATE TEXTURE
    GLuint textures[2];
    glGenTextures(2, textures);

    int width, height;
    unsigned char * image;

    //texture1
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    image = SOIL_load_image("resources/res/images/green.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    // glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "ourTexture1"), 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);


    //texture2
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);

     image = SOIL_load_image("resources/res/images/img1.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
     SOIL_free_image_data(image);
     glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "ourTexture2"), 1);
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);



    //parameters
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
    //filtering
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glGenerateMipmap( GL_TEXTURE_2D );


    //loop
    while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        glfwPollEvents( );

        //render
        glClearColor( 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        //draw triangle
        //if
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "ourTexture1"), 0);


        //draw container
        glBindVertexArray( VAO );
        glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0 );
        glBindVertexArray( 0 );

        glfwSwapBuffers( window );
    }

    //de-alocated stuff
    glDeleteVertexArrays( 1, &VAO );
    glDeleteBuffers( 1, &VBO );
    glDeleteBuffers( 1, &EBO );

    glfwTerminate( );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And here's the texture frag

```
    #version 330 core
    in vec3 ourColor;
    in vec2 TexCoord;

    out vec4 color;

    uniform sampler2D ourTexture1;
    uniform sampler2D ourTexture2;
    uniform int usetexture = 0;

    void main()
    {
        if (usetexture == 0)
            color = texture(ourTexture1, TexCoord);
        if (usetexture == 1)
            color = texture(ourTexture1, TexCoord);
    }
```

How do I call them properly and make them switch ? Even one texture doesn't show. I want to change between img1 and img2 from SOIL load image. But has been stuck. Any advice ?

Comment: In the c++ code you bind both textures at the same binding point `0`, and in the shader you use `ourTexture1` in both cases.

Comment: @t.niese I've updated my code.

Comment: You have to set `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);` for the first texture and 
 `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);`  for the 2nd one. Clear the color and depth buffer at the begin of each frame in the game loop - [`glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml)

Comment: @Rabbid76 I believe I have set glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); for both texture.  I've followed your suggestion for glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT ); , still not working.

Comment: You still use `texture(ourTexture1, TexCoord)` for `usetexture == 0` and `usetexture == 1`. And why do you rebind `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0])` to `0`over and over again?

Comment: @raisa_ Where do you install the shader program - [`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml)?

Comment: @raisa_ You have to change the value of `usetexture` in the game loop, to switch the textures - `int usetexture = 0; // or 1` `glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "usetexture"), usetexture);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to bind the 1st texture to texture unit 0 (`GL_TEXTURE0`) and the 2nd texture to texture unit 1 (`GL_TEXTURE1`):

```
GLuint textures[2];
int width, height;
unsigned char * image;

glGenTextures(2, textures);

// testure 1
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

image = SOIL_load_image("resources/res/images/green.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
SOIL_free_image_data(image);

// texture 2
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);

glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

image = SOIL_load_image("resources/res/images/red.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
SOIL_free_image_data(image);
```

The values of the texture sampler uniforms `ourTexture1` and `ourTexture2`, hav to be the numbers of the texture units 0 and 1.
The value of the uniforms cam be set, after the shader program object is installed as a part of the current rendering state ([`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml)):

```
// complie shaders and link shader program (glLinkProgram)
Shader ourShader( "resources/shaders/core.vs", "resources/shaders/core.frag" );
GLint tex1_loc = glGetUniformLocation( ourShader.Program, "ourTexture1" );
GLint tex2_loc = glGetUniformLocation( ourShader.Program, "ourTexture2" );

glUseProgram( ourShader.Program );
glUniform1i( tex1_loc, 0 );
glUniform1i( tex2_loc, 1 );
```

To choose/switch between the textures, I recommend to use the glsl function [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml).
The function interpolates between 2 values.
The 3rd parameter is a floating point value in range [0.0, 1.0], which defines the linear interpolation between the 1st and 2nd parameter.
If the 3rd parameter of `mix` is 0.0, the the result of the function is the 1st parameter. If it is 1.0, then the result is the 2nd parameter.
This allows you to crate a mixture of both texture or to draw on of them completely.

The fragment shader may look like this:

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture1;
uniform sampler2D ourTexture2;
uniform float mixtexture;

void main()
{
    vec4 color1 = texture(ourTexture1, TexCoord);
    vec4 color2 = texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord);
    color       = mix(color1, color2, mixtexture);
}
```

To test the code you can use the following loop, which creates a transition form `ourTexture1` to `ourTexture2`:

```
GLint mix_loc = glGetUniformLocation( ourShader.Program, "mixtexture" ); 
GLfloat mix_value = 0.0; // in [0.0, 1.0]
while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glUniform1f(mix_loc, mix_value);
    mix_value = mix_value >= 1.0f ? 0.0f : mix_value + 0.01f;

    glBindVertexArray( VAO );
    glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0 );
    glBindVertexArray( 0 );

    glfwSwapBuffers( window );
    glfwPollEvents( );
}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much ! I see now what steps were missing from my code. Also a very detailed explanation, it's a lot easier to understand your explanation than the tutorial I was following. I learned a lot from your answer. Thank you.